# ocsigenserver: You are not allowed to use port 80

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

When I run `make run.byte` I get this error `ocsigenserver: ocsigen:main: Fatal - You are not allowed to use port 80.`. I've tried `sudo make run.byte` but sudo doesn't know about opam or ocsigenserver. I've tried to play with `wwwuser` in the Makefile.options, but I can't make it work.
The README generated by the distillery doesn't give much information, and I can't find anything online.

`make test.byte` works just fine.

Any idea please?

edit:
It looks like it has nothing to do with eliom/ocaml, non root users just can't run anything on ports lower than 1024 on Ubuntu. But I still don't understand why the distillery suggests that I can do it if my wwwuser is me, I don't think there's any way this is ever going to work.
I also don't understand how I am supposed to run `sudo make run.byte`, opam is installed in my ~ directory, sudo cannot find `ocsigenserver`.
I could make it work by running everything as root, but anytime I run an `opam` command as root I get the `you shouldn't use opam as root` warning. I don't think this is the way I'm supposed to run it. Something's not right.

Comment: Usually people don't run their applications on a privileged port, but instead they run `nginx`(or some other web server) on port 80 or 443 and proxy to the application port accordingly.

Comment: Why not just `sudo ./run.byte`?

Answer (score 3):

With previous release of eliom (eliom.5.0.0) - I have not used yet the fresh 6.0.0 release - you have to install first your eliom application :

> sudo make install

Then you have to kill the process listening to the 80/tcp port (ex: `sudo netstat -tulpn 80 | grep :80` will help identify the process listening to that port - most likely apache2 or lighthttpd).

Then, you run your executable:

> sudo PATH=$PATH OCAMLPATH=$OCAMLPATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   make run.byte

This is what is written in README created with eliom-distillery - but take care to set your env variables before :

```
 OCAMLPATH is the location of ocaml used in your env (in my env :~/.opam/4.02.3/bin). 
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH : .opam/4.02.3/lib/stublibs (otherwise dllssl_threads_stubs is not found)
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work because I didn't know that I had to set myself those 2 variables first. Merci Pierre.